# Javascript How to force to click key?

Tags: javascript, html, css

force someone to click a key with javascript code.
For example:

```
$("#gameCanvas").mousedown(function(ev){
  if(ev.which == 3)
  {
  this blank is for that want.
  } });
```

I want to force users to click space button when they clicked right mouse as you see.

Comment: Why don't you just call whatever function would be called when they press the space key?

Comment: @Barmar is right. Also, I don't think you can "force" a click. However, I wonder if you can do a `setInterval` then open a new window?

Comment: there is no code for space button.
it is not a link.

Comment: What do you mean there's no code? You don't have a handler for something like `keyup` that does something when the user presses the space key? What does pressing the space key do?

Comment: if users press space it will jump, but i don't know jump codes from game.

Comment: Note that you _can_ force a click (or any event for that matter) by using the jQuery `trigger()` method (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Can you give me a code for that space click (key code: 32)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a solution like the following one. This the [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to the jQuery api doc.

```
$("#gameCanvas").mousedown(function(ev){
  if(ev.which == 3)
  {
    // Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
    var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 32 } );

    // trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 32
    jQuery( "body" ).trigger( e );
} });
```